# finding doublets

Tags: python, iterator

I have implemented the python code for finding the doublets. But it takes long time to run.

The link attached above is using network call but i want to read from the file.

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Thu Aug 22 23:21:07 2019
"""

import re
import itertools
import networkx

def differ_by_one(word1, word2):
    # Make sure word1 is shorter or equal in length to word2
    if len(word2) < len(word1):
        word1, word2 = word2, word1
    if len(word2) - len(word1) > 1:
        # Words differ in length by 2 or more characters so return False
        return False
    elif len(word1) == len(word2):
        # Words are same length so check how many characters are different
        # and return True if exactly one
        n_chars_diff = sum(c1 != c2 for c1, c2 in zip(word1, word2))
        return n_chars_diff == 1
    else:
        # word2 is guaranteed to be one character longer than word1.
        # Chop out one character at a time from word2 and compare to word1.
        for i in range(len(word2)):
            word2_shortened = word2[:i] + word2[i + 1:]
            if word1 == word2_shortened:
                return True
        return False
```

Answer (score 0):

> Program takes long time to run while Finding the doublets.

Below is some code cleanup and bug fixing that doubles the speed when the two words are the same length.  The key is to avoid `sum()` as it keeps adding after we know it's no good:

```
def differ_by_one(word1, word2):
    len_word1, len_word2 = len(word1), len(word2)

    if abs(len_word2 - len_word1) > 1:
        # Words differ in length by 2 or more characters so return False
        return False

    # word1 is equal in length to word2
    if len_word1 == len_word2:
        # Words are same length so check how many characters
        # are different and return True if exactly one
        n_chars_diff = 0

        for c1, c2 in zip(word1, word2):
            if c1 != c2:
                n_chars_diff += 1

                if n_chars_diff > 1:
                    return False

        return n_chars_diff == 1  # detects n_chars_diff == 0 case

    # Make sure word1 is shorter in length to word2
    if len_word2 < len_word1:
        word1, word2 = word2, word1
        len_word2 = len_word1

    # word2 is guaranteed to be one character longer than word1.
    # Chop out one character at a time from word2 and compare to word1.
    for i in range(len_word2):
        word2_shortened = word2[:i] + word2[i + 1:]

        if word1 == word2_shortened:
            return True

    return False
```

Unfortunately, my above changes add no improvement for words of unequal length.  In my word list tests, that's where 80% of your time is spent.  Anything you can do to speed up your code that tests unequal length words will make a **huge** difference in the time it takes to run.

Comment: for this program I am reading from file. Do you think I need to use network.Graph?